# Multi hop SSH with certificate on bastion server

Tags: linux, authentication, ssl, ssh, scp

I have this situtation:

- my local machine
- a login server (with token implementation)
- a set of machines accessible only with another authentication from login server (token implementation too)

this is what i currently do to reach host1:

localhost -> ssh to login server -> ssh to host1

considering that authentication over host1 require a passphrase hosted on login server

- is it possible to authenticate to host1 form localhost in one sigle command using for authentication over host1 the certificate hosted on login server?
- is it possible to do the same trick with scp?
  i'd like to upload a file to host1 in a single step, now i have to perform 2 step upload, first on login server then to host1...
  i imagine something like this would be possible:

scp myfile.txt myusername@host1:/tmp

thanks

Comment: google authentication agent forwarding

Comment: i'd like to use ssh and scp only without external applications

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.